# Python mysql does not commit

Tags: python, mysql

Having worked with other programming/scripting languages, I am completely baffled by Python's mysql interface (I am a bit new to Python) I am unable to commit my changes. I have stripped the code to the bare minimum:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import mysql.connector as mariadb

mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(
    user='testdb', 
    password='testdb',
    database='testdb',
    host='127.0.0.1',
    autocommit=True
)
mariadb_connection.autocommit=True
cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor(buffered=True)
cursor.execute( "UPDATE testdb SET descr='konijn' WHERE number=14549")
mariadb_connection.commit()
mariadb_connection.close()
```

I would have expected that the autocommit would do the trick, but it doesn't. Also, the `mariadb_connection.commit()` does nothing to commit the changes.
The database is (for as much as relevant):

```
    number      INTEGER,
    type        VARCHAR(255),
    file        VARCHAR(255),
    year        INTEGER,
    month       INTEGER,
    descr       VARCHAR(4096)
```

I am able to commit changes using the same credentials using TCL/Tk, so it should not be a permission problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that `number` is of type int in the database?

Comment: Yes. Added the description of the table to the question.

Comment: Interesting. What do you get from `print(cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM testdb WHERE number=14549""").fetchall())`?

Comment: for `select number,year,month,descr from testdb WHERE number=14549` I get `14549 2009 7  tremolat`. When I do the update, the pythonscript will actually see the table as being updated. So a `select` after the `update` will show an updated table. But when the script ends, everything is rolled-back.

Comment: Ok, I agree that's odd. I cannot see what you've done wrong in your code for commit not to work.

Comment: As a last-ditch guess, do you possibly have multiple active connections that have been overlooked during your effort to strip the code back?

Comment: How are you verifying that it hasn't committed?

Comment: the `mariadb_connection` is a global variable in my script. Anyway, I would have expected the stripped-down version to do a correct update of the database. And I would have expected (after having Read The Fine Manual) that both the `autocommit=True` and the `commit()` should be sufficient.

Comment: After the script is ended, I do a `mysql -u testdb -h localhost --password=testdb testdb`  from the shell prompt and `select number,year,month,descr from testdb WHERE number=14549;`

Comment: I ran the stripped-down code. When I encounter a problem that I cannot explain, I reduce the script to the bare minimum of what the functionality would do. In that way I do not have any interference from other Python concepts that I'm not completely familiar with (like the %s you normally use in sql-statements).

Comment: What does [`cursor.rowcount`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-rowcount.html) say?

Comment: Hey: that is odd? `cursor.rowcount=0`. Where, if I try a different

Comment: number, for example 14560, the rowcount becomes 1 the first time and 0 the second time. Hm.. I have to look into that. I'll get back when/if I get the solution. Sorry for the splitting of this comment; there is a time limit of 5 minutes I did not know.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After a server reboot (unrelated to this), I am now unable to reproduce my problem. Everything works as expected. I would have loved to know what was wrong, but it seems to have been more a server/configuration problem than a programming issue.

For the benefit of those who stumble upon this question looking for wisdom
(ahem) a small explanation of what I learned.

Contrary to the  other languages I use (Perl, TCL) I use frequently, Python turns autocommit off by default. Also, the mysql CLI starts with autocommit on. But Python's PEP0249 states:

> Note that if the database supports an auto-commit feature, this must
> be initially off. An interface method may be provided to turn it back
> on

.

The problem is that if a session that has autocommit disabled ends without
explicitly committing the final transaction, MySQL rolls back that transaction.

So, you have three choices:

- Turn on autocommit
- Explicitly commit your changes
- Lose your data  :-)

Turning on autocommit can be done directly when you connect to a database:

```
import mysql.connector as mariadb
connection = mariadb.connect(user='testdb', password='testdb',
    database='testdb', host='127.0.0.1',autocommit=True)
```

or separately:

```
connection.autocommit=True
```

Explicitly committing the changes is done with

```
connection.commit()
```

Note that the commit is done via the connection to the database, not via the cursor.

Additionally, I thought it might have been a locking issue, but with this
script:

```
import mysql.connector as mariadb
number=input('->')
mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(user='testdb', password='testdb',database='testdb', host='127.0.0.1')
cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor(buffered=True)
cursor.execute( "UPDATE testdb SET descr='konijntje' WHERE number=%s",(number,))
print 'rowcount',cursor.rowcount
number=input('->')
mariadb_connection.commit()
mariadb_connection.close()
```

I could verify that the second launch on the same record waits until the first releases the lock.

So thank you for your time, patience and reassurance that my code was not as wrong as I thought it was.

Answer (score -3):

Commit () statement can be used only in update,delete,and in insert command not possible in select and other commands

Comment: Really? How about REPLACE, LOAD DATA etc. ?!